# Single colorbar for alpha blended filled contours

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw two filled contours with alpha blending, and a colorbar to match resulting plot. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.random((10, 10))

plt.contourf(arr, 10)
plt.contourf(arr, 10, cmap='coolwarm', levels=np.arange(0, 1, .2), alpha=.5)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: screenshot]

draws colorbar for last contour.

I tried also this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.random((10, 10))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cax = ax.contourf(arr, 10)
cb = fig.colorbar(cax)

cax = ax.contourf(arr, 10, cmap='coolwarm', levels=np.arange(0, 1, .2), alpha=.5)
cb.update_bruteforce(cax)

plt.show()
```

which doesn't give me expected result:

[image: screenshot]

How to draw colorbar that matches actual plot in this example?

Comment: So am i correct to assume you basically want a new colormap which for 2/3 is your default (jet?), and for 1/3 coolwarm? If you define how you want to add those up you can make a new colormap and use it in the colorbar.

Comment: Alpha is `0.5` not `0.33`, but it doesn't really matter as it's just an example. Creating manually new colormap is bad idea.

Comment: If you use 1 colormap for the default 1.0 and the other for 0.5 you get 2/3 and 1/3. I dont understand why you want to use two colormaps in your plot, but dont want to combine them for the colorbar. Do you want two separate colorbars?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. If you think that making new colormap is good idea, please post it as answer. If it solves the problem, I'll accept it